# Using Unity to Dependency Inject IRepository<T> into the controller not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have a bunch of repository interface `IRepository<T>` where T is an entity class, the concrete implementation of `IRepository<T>` would be `ConcreteRepository<T>`, and I tried using this to register types:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IRepository<User>, ConcreteReposotory<User>>();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

And I intend the dependency to be solved when instantiate an controller uses IRepository, e.g:

```
public HomeControllr : Controller
{
    //[Dependency]
    IRepository<User> userRepo;
    public HomeController(IRepository<User> userRepo)
    {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }
}
```

But I couldn't make this to work, am I missing something here. I have tried to put '[Dependency]' attribute there, but still not working... Any advises?

Comment: Is the Controller being instantiated/managed by Unity?  Show the code where the HomeController gets created.

Comment: @Phil I followed this http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-03-12/asp_net-mvc_3-dependency-injection-unity_2 there is no need to create controller from unity

Comment: Looks like that's something built in to MVC?  The example you linked to uses property injection with an attribute, while your code uses constructor injection.  Not sure if that matters.

Comment: maybe that's the point, thanks

Comment: @baboonWorksFine what is the error you're getting?

Answer (score -1):

you should make the userRepo public and apply the [Dependency] attribute to it

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - An answer should have enough information to be helpful on its own. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.